# Estimating an integral and summation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

So I have an interval , say, $[a_1, a_2)$. I have partitioned this interval in the following manner: $$ a_1 \lt b_{11} \lt b_{12} \ldots \lt b_{1k_1}\lt a_2$$

Suppose I want to approximate the integral of some continuous functions say, $f(x)$ over the above integral:

$$ \int_{a_1}^{a_2} f(x)dx = \int_{a_1}^{b_{11}} f(x)dx + \int_{b_{11}}^{b_{12}} f(x)dx \ldots + \int_{b_{1k_1}}^{a_2} f(x)~dx~.$$

**Two questions:**

First, can I estimate the integral as follows:

$$ \int_{a_1}^{a_2} f(x)dx \approx f(a_1)(b_{11}-a_1) + f(b_{11})(b_{12}-b_{11}) + \ldots +f(b_{1k_1})(a_2-b_{1k_1}) ~?~~~~~~~(*)$$

Second, how can I write (*) as a single sum like

$$ \sum_{i=...}^{....} (\text{something})~? $$

Comment: You can even do better: replacing $f(x)$ by its minimum/maximum in every interval, you will find a bracketing of the integral value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: thanks for your comment. could you please expand on that.

Comment: $$\sum {\min}_k(b_k-a_k)\le I\le\sum{\max}_k(b_k-a_k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f$ is coontinuous in $[a_1,a_2]$, then it is Riemann integrable. What you wrote is actually a particular Riemann sum. And because when you make the partition finer, the Riemann sum tends to the value of the integral, then YES, you can approximate the integral in this way.

$\int\limits_{a_1}^{a_2}{f(x)dx}\sim \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k_1}{f(b_{1i})(b_{1i+1}-b_{1 i}))}$

where $b_{10}:=a_1$ and $b_{1k_1+1}:=a_2$

Comment: Thanks. Quick question. In general, how does one partition intervals of the form $[a_{i-1}, a_i)$ and then integrate over the integral.?

Comment: It is most often used an uniform grid. Also if you are in to numerical methods, I advice you to take a look  on the rectangle rule and trapezoidal rule for numerical integration. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule
If the function is even smoother, then you can get the order of approximation by the width of the intervals.